# My useEffect is getting response from Axios.get, but not setting state to it

Tags: reactjs

```
 useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/getUsers").then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      setListOfUsers(response.data);
      console.log(listOfUsers);
    });
  }, []);
```

- It consoles response.data perfectly, but console.log(listOfUsers) returns an empty array. How is this possible?

Comment: because updated state will be available in the next render, you can put `console.log(listOfUsers);` in the body of your component and checking the result.

Comment: It worked. Thank you.